# Selenium Grid2 Display Error

Tags: selenium-grid

I've been working on setting up Selenium Grid2 in the cloud and I'm now getting an error that I cannot figure out.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7057 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
  Error: no display specified
  Error: no display specified
```

I've started two nodes - Hub and WebDriver

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role hub -port 7055
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role webdriver  -hub http://ec2-54-244-219-84.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7055/grid/register
```

I've installed Xvfb and I've started a screen using.

```
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
```

I've also set the display environment variable.

```
export DISPLAY=:99
```

I'm trying to run a simple test on Amazon EC2.

```
require 'headless'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

# Start the headless browser
headless = Headless.new
headless.start
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :url => "http://localhost:7055/wd/hub")

# Print google.com's title
browser.get('http://google.com')
puts browser.title

# Close the browser
browser.quit
headless.destroy
```

Or from my local machine

```
require 'headless'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

# Start the headless browser
headless = Headless.new
headless.start
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :url => "http://ec2-54-244-205-27.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7055/wd/hub")

# Print google.com's title
browser.get('http://google.com')
puts browser.title

# Close the browser
browser.quit
headless.destroy
```

But I still get the above error...

```
Error: no display specified
```

Also, when I try to run FireFox from Command Line...

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What solved this issue for me was doing the following...

Instead of running the webdriver node like this...

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role webdriver  -hub http://ec2-54-244-219-84.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7055/grid/register
```

I added xvfb-run before the command...

```
xvfb-run java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role webdriver  -hub http://ec2-54-244-219-84.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7055/grid/register
```